# can SSL encrypt and decrypt with one key in java

Tags: java, ssl, aes, des

I have project to transfer data from client to server and I use ssl in java and I use one key to encrypt and decryption 
I use keytool to create the key

server
Security.addProvider(new Provider());

```
        //Specifying the Keystore details
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","testkeystore.ks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","mypass");

        // Enable debugging to view the handshake and communication which happens between the SSLClient and the SSLServer
        // System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","all");
    }


            // Initialize the Server Socket
            SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
            sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket)sslServerSocketfactory.createServerSocket(intSSLport);
```

client
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/home/lap/NetBeansProjects/Dionaea-001/testkeystore.ks");

```
    {
        // Registering the JSSE provider
        Security.addProvider(new Provider());
    }

    try {
        // Creating Client Sockets
        SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket)sslsocketfactory.createSocket(strServerName,intSSLport);
```

my questions 
it is possible to use one key in SSL?
how I can know the type of encryption AES or DES?

Answer (score 1):

The certificate and private key in your server keystore are only used for authenticating the server.

With SSL/TLS, the encryption keys are shared keys negotiated during the handshake.

You can see which encryption algorithm from the [cipher suites](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider) that is used, which you can get from the `SSLSession` once you've established the connection. (You can get the session from the `SSLSocket`.)